# Webpart-sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a web part and a button click event. The page should be refreshed after submitting the button so that I get latest values from the database.

Could any body suggest me is there any method that will make the page refresh.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a ASP.NET `LinkButton` or `Button`, it will automatically refresh the page as a result of postback.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx